# Determine size of html table in razor generated view

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Edited**
*I've reworded this question as it has been marked as too broad.*

I'm using razor engine to create strongly typed email templates and I'd like to find the height of a particular table cell within the generated HTML.

I'm generating the HTML like this

```
var templateService = new TemplateService();

var emailHtmlBody = templateService.Parse(File.ReadAllText(template.TemplateFilePath), template, null, null);
```

This creates a string of the html, is there anyway of determining the height (which is dynamic) of a particular html element using mvc or the razor engine or do I need to use a rendering engine to first render the html and then use a technique like a JavaScript query to get the value.

I'm running this in a WCF application so the rendering engine needs to be headless - the standard .net browser control will not work.

I've had success with third party libraries (see my proposed answer), is there a better way to do this without the use of these?

Comment: Are you assigning the height or it totally dynamic ?

Comment: I don't see how this is "too broad". The OP is not asking for a fully coded solution, but rather asking whether there is an angle to attack the problem from.

Comment: You have tagged this ASP.NET MVC, and you are asking this for a WCF application? I believe that is where the broadness confusion is comming from :-) Why are you even trying to use razor in a WCF app? To help further, please also provide exactly from where and to where this string will be returned from/to.

Comment: As explained I'm using razor to generate strongly typed email templates, which works perfectly well. My question doesn't concern WCF, that just happens to be where I'm hosting this as our other apps will call this service to send emails, but rather how best to render the html generated to extract a value. I thought there might be a way to do this using razor or mvc but have found using a third partly headless renderer to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've found of doing this is to parse the view, save the generated html (with the required JavaScript) to a web server (or locally, ymmv), then load the page in a headless browser like `SimpleBrowser.WebDriver` (Alternatives `awesomium` or `webkit.net` - apparently you can run these in a headless mode) and then return the rendered html giving you the values you required from the js script.

I'll mark this as the answer, I'd be interested if there are any simpler approaches though.

Answer (score 1):

This depands on where you will use the height really. If you need it withing the page, you can always use JavaScript. One way to do this would be to give your table an id attribute and use a simple JavaScript function to determine the height of that table. This function can reside at the end of your layout page.

```
<script>
    var tableHeight = 0;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        tableHeight = document.getElementById('tableId').style.offsetheight;
    });
</script>
```

You can access `tableHeight` in any javascript code globally afterwards. If, on the other hand, you need to use this on the serverside code, then you need to assign it to an input variable that you host in your model and retreive it in an `[HttpPost]` action method.

Comment: How would I go about using HttpPost action? Sorry, I've never really worked with mvc, I'm only using razor so I can create strongly typed email templates. I basically need a way of having a string returned with the rendered html.

Comment: Do you need the string within the generated html or when you submit the html?

Comment: I just need the rendered output of the html with javascript returned as a string.

Comment: you can't really get a render attribute (e.g. height) before the rendering takes place. So what you can do is use the JavaScript in this answer to get the height attribute after the rendering is done (document ready runs after all is rendered). If you want to output this, or use it however you want, the JavaScript variable "tableHeight" will give you that anywhere on the page. just give your table "id = tableId" and put this script somewhere. Try wrting `tableHeight` to the browser consele afterwards.

Comment: Of course, you could also determine for each template a specific height, and put it in your html before anything happens and you'll know the table height as well :-)